# ¿Como invierto un bucle while para que se imprima al reves?

Tags: php, mysql, bucles

¡Hola! Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?>
            <div class="box">
                <h2 class="h2-notif"><?php echo "$titulo" ?></h2>
                <p class="p-notif"><?php echo "$texto" ?></p><br>
            </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Esta es la query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
```

Basicamente, es un panel que muestra las notificaciones, el problema es que las notificaciones mas nuevas se imprimen hacia abajo, ¿Como puedo hacer que se impriman al reves?, es decir, que las notificaciones mas nuevas se impriman arriba de todo.

¡Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Comment: Ordena la query para que vengan al reves...

Comment: No se como hacer eso, ahora agrego la query a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo desde la query, por ejemplo SELECT * FROM tu_tabla ORDER BY titulo DESC
con esto haces la consulta de forma inversa

Comment: ahi acabo de subir mi query, como utilizo el order by y el desc? no conocia estas funciones

Comment: es decir, yo uso ids, deberia hacer esto: "SELECT * FROM notificaciones ORDER BY id DESC WHERE usuario = '$usuario'"?

Comment: lee por favor [answer].. se pide que las respuestas expliquen la solucion, y siempre trata de contestar una vez que la pregunta este completa.. Gracias por el aporte!!!

Comment: @SilviaManquis usas id para que?? vos queres ordernar por fecha o por cual campo??? por favor, aclaralo en la pregunta...

Comment: Uso id para poder eliminar la notificacion y poder identificarla de otras, no se usar fechas, igual no es necesario ya que con las id deberia funcionar

Comment: Así es, lo qué pasa es que ORDER BY te sirve para ordenarlo por el campo que tú selecciones por ejemplo por el campo id que me imagino que es de tipo numérico, la instrucción ORDER BY en sql tiene 2 opciones ASC y DESC si tú solo pones ORDER BY id por default lo interpreta como ORDER BY id ASC que significa ordenar en orden ascendente y te devolvería 1,2,3,4... pero si tú pones ORDER BY id DESC te lo ordenara de orden descendente y te devolvería ...,4,3,2,1

Comment: Ah genial, edita tu pregunta, esa es la respuesta ¡Gracias!

Comment: Love you, gracias por la respuesta detallada